# What is physics of Collision between solid and liquid (or gas)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-mechanics

My mind has been busy recently by this question:

What is physics of Collision between solid and liquid (or gas)?

What is Conservation law's of such Collision?

Why, when we drop a solid object in water, water shows an Strange behavior (infact what is Conservation law's of energy and momentum when we drop a solid object in water )?

Figure 1: Strange behavior of water after impact

[image: Strange behavior of water after impact]
<sub>(source: [streetwise.co](http://wp.streetwise.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/water-drop.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What Strange behaviour your means? It is just normal particle particle collision, but involves billions of billions of them. Read Brownian motions and you will understand.

Comment: Maybe @Guest want some references.

Comment: Image currently not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fluids, conservation of mass and momentum are still applicable, only not that easily, because there are internal forces in a fluid, i.e. caused by viscosity.

In liquids, conservation of mass is described by the [continuity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation), while the conservation of momentum is described by the [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations)

Of course, you can incorporate the effect the solid has in these equation, but this easier said than done, and large depends on the properties of the solid,